# Using a lua rock installed with luarocks

Tags: package-management, mysql, lua

I wanted to install `luasql.mysql` with `luarocks`, and I've ran into a problem. Even though the packages were installed providing `mysql.h`, luarocks couldn't find it. I solved it eventually:

```
luarocks install luasql-mysql MYSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/mysql
```

Now, all prerequisites should be met, to use `luasql.mysql`, but I'm getting an error:

```
> require "luasql.mysql"
stdin:1: module 'luasql.mysql' not found:
    no field package.preload['luasql.mysql']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/luasql/mysql.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/luasql/mysql/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/luasql/mysql.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/luasql/mysql/init.lua'
    no file './luasql/mysql.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/luasql/mysql.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/luasql/mysql/init.lua'
    no file './luasql/mysql.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/luasql/mysql.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/luasql/mysql.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/luasql/mysql.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './luasql/mysql.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/luasql.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/luasql.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/luasql.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './luasql.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Now, in that list, there is no `/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/` or anything like that. Also, I can't seem to find a `mysql.lua`.

According to luarocks, `luasql-mysql` is installed correctly, though:

```
% luarocks list

Installed rocks:
----------------

luasql-mysql
   2.3.0-1 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
```

I believe I did something wrong, but I have no idea where. Also, it seems Lua is quite obscure when it comes to installing additional packages...

Comment: Can anyone know how to configure MariaDB with Lua. I have tried to luarocks install luasql.mysql, its says Error: Could not find expected file mysql.h for MYSQL -- you may have to install MYSQL in your system and/or pass MYSQL_DIR or MYSQL_INCDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install luasql-mysql MYSQL_DIR=/usr/local I have tried to locate the mysql.h, but i cant able to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I solved it, and it was quite a stupid mistake:

`luasql.mysql` is [only available for Lua 5.1](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/index.html#status), *not* Lua 5.2, which I use by default. Running `lua5.1` solves the issue:

```
% lua5.1       
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require "luasql.mysql"
>
```

...and all is good.

*Sorry to have created a confusion...*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set `lua.package_cpath` or `lua.package_path` in your LUA script?

Or set `LUA_CPATH` and `LUA_PATH` environment variable?

i.e `export LUA_PATH='/usr/local/lib/luarocks/?.so'; lua ./XX.lua`